# Why doesn’t the alternation (pipe) operator ( | ) in JavaScript regular expressions give me two matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my regular expression:

```
"button:not([DISABLED])".match(/\([^()]+\)|[^()]+/g);
```

The result is:

```
["button:not", "([DISABLED])"]
```

Is it correct? I'm confused. Because the (pipe) operator `|` means "or", I think the correct result is:

```
["button:not", "[DISABLED]", "([DISABLED])"]
```

Because this:

```
["button:not", "[DISABLED]"]
```

is the result of:

```
"button:not([DISABLED])".match(/[^()]+/g);
```

and this:

```
["([DISABLED])"]
```

is the result of:

```
"button:not([DISABLED])".match(/\([^()]+\)/g);
```

But the result output in console tell me the result is:

```
["button:not", "([DISABLED])"]
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: @RobW Yes, because this question is not about JS at all.

Comment: @RobW: It's the pipe symbol in code ticks inside parenthesis `:-/`

Comment: Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html.

Comment: @Tomalak I don't know what RobW originally said, but *all* regex questions should mention the language/environment/flavor they apply to. Just because one individual question might be simple enough to apply to all flavors, I wouldn't discourage mentioning the language, as it's necessary more often than not (and how is the OP supposed to know if other flavors do the same thing).

Comment: @user2155362 the basic thing you need to know about *all* global regex applications: matches can never overlap. period. the parenthesized case produces your second match, but the third one you want overlaps with that (in fact, is a substring of it), so you cannot obtain it this way. acdcjunior's answer provides a bit more reasoning. but the point to take away is: *matches can never overlap*

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The regex

```
/\([^()]+\)|[^()]+/g
```

Basically says: There are two options, match (1) `\([^()]+\)` **OR** (2) `[^()]+`, wherever you see any of them (`/g`).

Let's iterate at your sample string so you understand the reason behind the obtained result.

Starting string:

```
button:not([DISABLED])
```

Steps:

- The cursor begins at the char **`b`** <sup>(actually it begins at the start-of-string anchor, `^`, but for this example it is irrelevant)</sup>.
- Between the two available options, **`b`** can only match the **(2)**, as the **(1)** requires a starting **`(`**.

  - Now that it has begun to match the  **(2)**, it will keep on matching it all the way, meaning it will consume everything that's not a **`(`** or **`)`**.
  - From the item above, it consumes everything up to (and including) the **`t`** char (because the next char is a **`(`** which does not match `[^()]+`) thus **leaving `button:not` as first matched string**.
- <sub><sup>(room for clarity)</sup></sub>
- Now the cursor is at **`(`**. Does it begin to match any of the options? Yes, the first one: `\([^()]+\)`.

  - Again, now that it has begun to match the **(1)**, it will go through it all the way, meaning it will consume everything that's not a **`(`** or **`)`**   **until** it finds a **`)`** <sup>(if while consuming it finds a **`(`** before  a **`)`**, it will backtrack as that will mean the **(1)** regex was ultimately not matched)</sup>.
  - Now it keeps consuming all the remaining characters until it finds **`)`**, **leaving then `([DISABLED])` as second matched string**.
- <sub><sup>(room for clarity)</sup></sub>
- Since we have reached the last character, the regex processing ends.

---

**Edit:** There's a very useful [online tool](http://www.debuggex.com/) that allows you to see the regex in a graphical form. Maybe it helps to understand how the regex will work:

[image: Regular expression image]

You can also move the cursor step by step and see what I tried to explain above: **[live link](http://www.debuggex.com/r/Vaw1qMzH5m0ieOb4)**.

**Note about the precedence of expressions separed by `|`:** Due to the way the JavaScript regex engine process the strings, the order in which the expressions appear matter. It will evaluate each alternative in the order they are given. If one is those options is matched to the end, it will not attempt to match any other option, even if it could. Hopefully an example makes it clearer:

```
"aaa".match(/a|aa|aaa/g); // ==> ["a", "a", "a"]
"aaa".match(/aa|aaa|a/g); // ==> ["aa", "a"]
"aaa".match(/aaa|a|aa/g); // ==> ["aaa"]
```

Comment: wah, so clear. Thanks for your replay, it realy help. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Your understanding of the alternation operator seems to be incorrect. It does not look for *all* possible matches, only for the *first* one that matches (from left to right).

Consider `(a | b)` as "match **either** `a` **or** `b`".

See also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: But `[^()]+|\([^()]+\)` Gives the same longest match `([DISABLED])` result for me. instead of `[DISABLED]`.

Comment: That's because the string is processed from left to right and `\([^()]+\)` matches earlier in the string (at the `(`) and consumes all the character until the end..

Comment: Simple example: `"baa".match(/aa|baa/);` will match `baa` because the first alternation (`aa`) does not match the first character (`b`), but the second does.

Comment: Thank for example. So whether it is similar to 2 threads, searching for its pattern in a string.? Instead of single thread searching for 2 patterns in a string one by one?

Comment: I don't understand your question and what you mean by "thread".

Comment: `"baa".match(/aa|baa/)` In this example, if I execute the /aa/ first , then b`aa` will be matched , hence I will not execute the match for `baa`. (like in case of `C || operator`). But If it is multi-thread., i.e one thread searches for `baa`, another thread searches for `aa`., now after reading `b`, it matches with with second thread. Hence the first thread dies, and **baa** is highlighted. Is that the case?

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads (JS has not threads). The string is matched from left to right. So the engine looks at the first character of the string (`a`) and the first character of the expression (`b`).  Thy are not the same, so it does not match. But since the expressions is an alternation, the engine will now try the first character of the alternative, which is `b`. Match! Now to the next character, `a` in the string and `a` in expression. Match! Next characters: `a` in the string and `a` in expression. Match! No characters left in string or expression. Done.

Comment: There *are* engines that work differently and will find the longest match (I think), but the JS regex engine is not one of those. For more info I recommend to read http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do.

Comment: @FelixKling there are engines that find the longest match, but they will still find the *leftmost* longest match, so that won't make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not very good on regular expressions, but I think they work by giving you one thing that matches them, rather than all things that could match them.

So, the `|` operator says: “give me something that matches the left regular expression, or something that matches the right regular expression”.

As your string contains something that matches the left regular expression, you just get that.

Answer (score -1):

Regex finds the *best* match, not all possible matches. The best match for that regex is `"([DISABLED])"`, not `"[DISABLED]"` which is a subset of the "better" match.

Consider the following example:

```
"123 456789".match( /[0-9]{4,6}/g )
```

You want to find the one number that is between 4 and 6 digits long. *If* the result would be all possible numbers that match the regex, it wouldn't be of much use:

```
[ "4567", "5678", "6789", "45678", "56789", "456789" ]   // you don't want this
```